# AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'createLBPHFaceRecognizer'

Tags: python, windows, opencv

I am facing some attribute error while running face recognizing the code. My face detects code run perfectly.But while I try to run the face recognizing code it shows some attribute error. I googled and tried to follow all the steps. But still, it shows the same error. Here is my code:

face recognition

[image: enter link description here]

and I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\MAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe C:/Users/MAN/PycharmProjects/facerecognition/Recognise/recognize1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/MAN/PycharmProjects/facerecognition/Recognise/recognize1.py", line 4, in <module>
    recognizer = cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'createLBPHFaceRecognizer'

Process finished with exit code 1.
```

I am using Windows platform. python 3.6 version.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include your code as *code*, not an image.

Answer (score 141):

You need to install opencv-contrib

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

It should work after that.

Comment: I wish I knew that before I have spent a couple of hours compiling opencv with contrib libs.

Comment: for me, I had to also uninstall the `opencv-python` by running `pip uninstall opencv-python`

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you!! I was getting an error cv2.cv2 does not have attribute name xphoto

Answer (score 21):

if you are using python3.x and opencv==4.1.0 then use following commands
First of all

```
python -m pip install --user opencv-contrib-python
```

after that use this in the python script

```
cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
```

Comment: I need this variant but no works on mac os 10.12.6 ,  gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0

Answer (score 8):

You might be running Python3 and therefore you are supposed to use pip3 to install the opencv-contrib package :

```
pip3 install opencv-contrib-python
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

Use the following

```
recognizer = **cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()**
```

After you install:

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

If using anaconda then in anaconda prompt:

```
conda install pip
```

then

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Comment: do you mean `pip install opencv-contrib-python`?  My pip says it does not find that distribution

Comment: am using anaconda3 but still am facing error as below:

model = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'face'

Comment: @SurajBhatt have you been able to solve it. I'm also facing the same issue

Comment: @TOLULOPE ADETULA not yet. still facing same error. actually am using anaconda3 not sure whether it conflict with version. If you able to solve pl post. thanks.

Comment: @SurajBhatt I don't know what I did in particular that solved the issue for me. 
I updated my OpenCV library and also 
**pip install opencv-contrib-python**. It first didn't work until I restarted my system

Comment: @TOLULOPEADETULA Great... Thanks for letting me know. let me try again with conda.

Answer (score 4):

opencv has changed some functions and moved them to their [opencv_contrib](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib) repo so you have to call the mentioned method with:

```
recognizer = cv2.face.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()
```

Note: You can see this [issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/7187) about missing docs. Try using help function `help(cv2.face.createLBPHFaceRecognizer)` for more details.

Answer (score 4):

I have some problem while executing :

```
import cv2 as cv
face_recognizer = cv.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
```

generating an error : cv2.cv2 has no face attributes.

if i try to install with :

```
sudo pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

it will take hours to compile and finally nothing works !

But on the site : https://www.piwheels.org/project/opencv-contrib-python/#install
only version 4.4.0.46 has files !

Then I try this :

```
sudo pip3 install opencv-contrib-python==4.4.0.46
```

installation is instantaneous !!!

I need to install some other libraries :

```
sudo apt install libaec0 libaom0 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk1.0-0 libatlas3-base libatspi2.0-0 libavcodec58 libavformat58 libavutil56 libbluray2 libcairo-gobject2 libcairo2 libchromaprint1 libcodec2-0.8.1 libcroco3 libdatrie1 libdrm2 libepoxy0 libfontconfig1 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgfortran5 libgme0 libgraphite2-3 libgsm1 libgtk-3-0 libharfbuzz0b libhdf5-103 libilmbase23 libjbig0 libmp3lame0 libmpg123-0 libogg0 libopenexr23 libopenjp2-7 libopenmpt0 libopus0 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0 libpixman-1-0 librsvg2-2 libshine3 libsnappy1v5 libsoxr0 libspeex1 libssh-gcrypt-4 libswresample3 libswscale5 libsz2 libthai0 libtheora0 libtiff5 libtwolame0 libva-drm2 libva-x11-2 libva2 libvdpau1 libvorbis0a libvorbisenc2 libvorbisfile3 libvpx5 libwavpack1 libwayland-client0 libwayland-cursor0 libwayland-egl1 libwebp6 libwebpmux3 libx264-155 libx265-165 libxcb-render0 libxcb-shm0 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxinerama1 libxkbcommon0 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxvidcore4 libzvbi0
```

It works well since when using import cv2 face !!

I have now in pip3 freeze :

```
opencv-contrib-python==4.4.0.46
opencv-python==4.5.1.48
```

Hope this will be usefull !!!!!

Answer (score 3):

For me changing createLBPHFaceRecognizer() to

```
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
```

fixed the problem

Answer (score 3):

I got openCV installed smoothly in my mac by:

```sh
$ brew install opencv
$ brew link --overwrite --dry-run opencv // to force linking
$ pip3 install opencv-contrib-python
```

I got it at windows 10 using:

```sh
c:\> pip3 install opencv-python
c:\> pip3 install opencv-contrib-python
```

Then I got it tested by

```sh
$ python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 09:23:15) 
[Clang 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'4.1.0'
>>> exit()
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem:

> module cv2 has no attribute "cv2.TrackerCSRT_create"

My Python version is 3.8.0 under Windows 10.
The problem was the opencv version installation.

So I fixed this way (cmd prompt with administrator privileges):

1. Uninstalled opencv-python: `pip uninstall opencv-python`
2. Installed **only** opencv-contrib-python: `pip install opencv-contrib-python`

Anyway you can read the following guide:

https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python

Answer (score 2):

```
python -m pip install --user opencv-contrib-python
```

After doing this just **Restart your system** and then if you are on Opencv >= 4.* use :
 `recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()`

This should solve 90% of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using PyCharm and installing `opencv-contrib-python-headless` solved it for me. I tried all the other solutions on this thread initially and none of them seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

### RESTART YOUR IDE

I tried all of the different things but nothing seems to be working then I just restarted my IDE and it worked like charm.

Still, if it does not work then try restarting your system.

FYI, I am working on the following versions

```
opencv-contrib-python==4.4.0.46
opencv-python==4.1.2.30
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to have OpenCV (3.4.2), Py-OpenCV (3.4.2), LibOpenCV (3.4.2).

My Python was version 3.5.6 with Anaconda in Windows OS 10.

Answer (score 0):

Check your OpenCV version

```
import cv2
cv2.__version__
```

If your are running Python v3.x and OpenCV v4 and above:

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Try running your program again. This should now work.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Python Interpreter Settings** in Pycharm / your IDE environment and change the package versions or install them in these versions.

opencv-contrib-python   == 4.4.0.46
opencv-python   == 4.1.2.30

Check Screenshot for clarity.

[image]