# Error in OpenCV code saying missing module 'face'

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

I am trying to implement face recognition code using `Python 2.7` and `OpenCV 3.4.1`, but I get an error when running the code:

```py
face_recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
```

The error message:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'face'

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Did you try looking into https://stackoverflow.com/q/44633378/5916727 ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install opencv-contrib-python. Opencv has moved some functions over to the contribution package.
Try running `pip install opencv-contrib-python` and then import that module.

Edit: This is assuming that you are using the regular opencv package, as this seems to be the most common problem.