# OpenCV AttributeError using python

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, face-detection

I am Building the Face Recognition and Identification model in python using the OpenCV library but when creating the recognizer I am getting this error I am new to OpenCV can anyone help me in this.

```
 import os
 import cv2 
 import numpy as np
 from PIL import Image
 import pickle
 BASE_DIR=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
 IMG_DIR=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"images")
 y_labels=[]
 current_ID=0
 labels_ids={}
 x_train=[]
 face_cascade=cv2.CascadeClassifier('cascades/data
      /haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml')
 recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
```

The error:

```
Open CV:AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'face'
```

LBPHFaceRecognizer is not Working

Answer (score 1):

You need to install opencv-contrib:

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

See this [Github issue](https://github.com/boubli/Face-Recognition-using-OpenCV-Python3/issues/1) and this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44633378/attributeerror-module-cv2-cv2-has-no-attribute-createlbphfacerecognizer).

Comment: I have tried this does not work

Comment: @Muhammad It is good practice to include what you have already *tried and didn't work* in your post...