# i'm getting attribute error even after i updated my opencv using opencv-contrib-python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

> AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'createLBPHFaceRecognizer'
>   I restarted my windows but still its not working

```
recognizer=cv2.face.createLBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'createLBPHFaceRecognizer'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44633378/attributeerror-module-cv2-cv2-has-no-attribute-createlbphfacerecognizer)

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your code. The method is called `LBPHFaceRecognizer_create`, not `createLBPHFaceRecognizer_create`.

The following works for me (after installing `opencv-contrib-python`):

```py
import cv2
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
```