# opencv installation issue in windows via the sources

Tags: python, opencv

i have been working on opencv installation via the source code, looks am not sucessfull with my installation
I checked out the latest opencv, opencv_contrib sources from the github repos and  followed the steps mentioned "[Install OpenCV-Python in Windows](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/de5/tutorial_py_setup_in_windows.html)" via the opencv documentation.

Solution of opencv is built sucessfully.

[image]

In the last step of the opencv installation document they mentioned to build the project INSTALL once it build scuessfully opencv-python will be installed in the machine
[image]

I tried by importing the cv2 using import cv2 at that time there is no error so then proceeded to verify opencv version then it is throwing error as below

[image]

Expected is to show the version of the opencv

How to validate the opencv installation is done properly?

Did i miss any step during this process?

Comment: have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/59511176/10407557 ?

Comment: after installing the opencv-contrib package i can see that opencv version installed is of 4.3.0 but am building the sources of 4.4.0