# cv2 has no attribute data

Tags: python, opencv

The code is from a book which teaching OpenCV. I ran the code but it always showing error.

```
import cv2 
casc_path = cv2.data.haarcascades + "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(casc_path)
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(casc_path)
faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(image, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=5, minSize=(30,30), flags = cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE)
imgheight=image.shape[0]
imgwidth=image.shape[1] 
cv2.rectangle(image, (10,imgheight-20), (110,imgheight), (0,0,0), -1)
cv2.putText(image,"Find " + str(len(faces)) + " face!", (10,imgheight-5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255,255,255), 2)
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w, y+h),(128,255,0),2)

cv2.namedWindow("facedetect")
cv2.imshow("facedetect", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)  
cv2.destroyWindow("facedetect")
```

And the error is here.

```
File "K:/pyCharm_object/OpevCV.py", line 2, in <module>
casc_path = cv2.data.harrcascades + "harrcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'data'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'createLBPHFaceRecognizer'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44633378/attributeerror-module-cv2-cv2-has-no-attribute-createlbphfacerecognizer)

Comment: or possibly with `pip install opencv-contrib-python --upgrade`

Comment: what version of OpenCV do you use? I have v4.1.1 handy and it does have `cv2.data.haarcascades`

Comment: the issue is not about needing contrib. not all import errors are due to the same reason.

Answer (score 4):

OpenCV comes with and [knows where to look for the pre-trained classifiers](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades).

You could omit that line and simply do:

```
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python --upgrade
```

As suggested by @Ruli in the comments has resolved this problem for me.

Answer (score -1):

Are you confident about the openCV package you have installed? If you have the

`opencv-contrib-python` package you shouldn't be looking at that error.

Answer (score -1):

Just find your location of haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml by searching in file explorer. Then copy the path of the required xml file and paste path in raw form:

```
casc_path = (r"**your path**\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
```

Example:

```
casc_path = (r"C:\Users\User_name\miniconda3\pkgs\libopencv-4.5.3-py39h4b6fd43_5\Library\etc\haarcascades\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
```

This worked for me. :)