# OpenCV for face detection: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'data' AND !empty() in function 'detectMultiScale'

Tags: python, opencv, face-detection

I would like to use HAAR to detect faces.

I first ran the following code:

```
#use HAAR cascade to detect faces
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

# Detect faces
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(img)
```

When doing so, I get the following error:
`error: OpenCV(4.1.0) /home/vocuser/tmp/xeus/4.1.opencv/opencv/modules/objdetect/src/cascadedetect.cpp:1658: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'detectMultiScale'`

I read that I am getting the error because the XML file could not be found. So I did the following:

```
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

# Detect faces
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(img)
```

But now I'm getting the following error:
`AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'data'`

So what is the correct approach? How can I use the `detectMultiScale` function?

Comment: Use the full path of the file.

Comment: I also did: 
cv2_base_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(cv2.__file__))

haar_model = os.path.join(cv2_base_dir, 'data/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

This also does not work.

Comment: for that first error, are you sure `img` isn't empty?

Comment: `!empty()` means the cascade couldn't be loaded. trust me, or look at the source code. -- if you used a recent version, instead of 4.1.0, you would be able to use `cv2.data.haarcascades`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cv2 has no attribute data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65357932/cv2-has-no-attribute-data)