# Can't install opencv package in a Raspberry pi

Tags: python, opencv, pip, raspberry-pi

So I am doing a face recognition project in a Raspberry Pi. It is a django project and when I run the server I get this error: `AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'face'`

I searched for the error and I came up with that I needed to install `opencv-contrib-python`

The problem is that when I try to install it the download gets to 99% and I get this: `'pip3 install opencv-contrib-pyt…' terminated by signal SIGKILL (Forced quit)`.

Does anyone know why this happens? how can I fix this? help is much appreciated

Comment: Try installing the headless version, `opencv-contrib-python-headless`?

Comment: remove **everything** related to opencv. all the pip packages you might have, all the apt/yum/whatever packages, everything. then install **only** `opencv-contrib-python` or its headless variant, not both, and not the non-contrib packages either. and check your disk usage and ram usage. if your disk is full, we can't help with that. -- and why did you tag `django`? that's irrelevant here.

Answer (score -2):

I got the same error and fixed it like this.

Try:

1. `sudo apt install python-opencv libopencv-dev`
2. y/n --> `y`
3. `sudo apt install python python-pip`
4. y/n --> `y`
5. `pip install opencv-python`

Comment: thank you, but does not work for me, I still get: AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'face'

Comment: Maybe this page can help you: ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44633378/attributeerror-module-cv2-cv2-has-no-attribute-createlbphfacerecognizer)