# module 'cv2' has no attribute 'face'

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I try to make face recognition using opencv. But iam facing some attribute error. I also installed pip install opencv-contrib-python library and reinstalled python.org software but still facing that error

[The code and output screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GloU7.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44633378/8878627

Comment: `opencv-python` conflicts with `opencv-contrib-python`. install **exactly one**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fix this problem with using this commands.

```
pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python

pip install opencv-contrib-python==4.4.0.46
```