# Python OpenCV, ' cv2 has no attribute 'face' '

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I was watching a course about Face Recognition in OpenCV from YouTube. But I am having trouble with a problem.

```
face_recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
```

When I write the codes you see above, it always says that when I run the program:

```
    face_recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
    AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'face'
```

I've looked for the solutions, most of people had said that if you install the library "opencv-contrib-python", it will be solved. And I installed it. But it didn't work neither.

Comment: How did you install OpenCV? Have you installed `opencv-contrib-python`?

Comment: Yeah, I've. I searched for it on internet, I think "opencv-contrib-python" worked for a lot of people, but I couldn't work it. :(

Comment: By the way, I installed OpenCV by CMD.

Answer (score 0):

You must download `opencv-contrib-python` package to solve this issue. Used the following pip install in your terminal.

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Also see the following answer:
[AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'createLBPHFaceRecognizer'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44633378/attributeerror-module-cv2-cv2-has-no-attribute-createlbphfacerecognizer)

Comment: I already downloaded this but it does nothing :(. I'm using the IDE 'PyCharm'. I also tried the VSCode but it does nothing either.

Comment: I highly recommend you to use anaconda  installation instead  PyCharm or VSCode. Also try downloading the pip install globally.

Comment: I tried to download "globally" but Pip says there's nothing called 'globally'.

Photo: https://ibb.co/Rh3BYrm

Comment: I think that you should read pip documentation ASAP:
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#

Comment: I can't solve it.

Comment: try this:
pip install opencv-contrib-python --user

Comment: I guess the module "cv2.face" was installed to my PC. I wrote print(cv2.face) and it said the module cv2.face existed. But I think I have one more problem. cv2.face doesn't look on autocomplete.