# I am creating a face recognition system using Python and OpenCV on these versions

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'face'

face_recognizer = cv2.face.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()

Comment: please take the [tour] and review [ask]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'createLBPHFaceRecognizer'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44633378/attributeerror-module-cv2-cv2-has-no-attribute-createlbphfacerecognizer)

Answer (score 1):

As stated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44641712/8228122), you have to install `opencv-contrib-python`

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Comment: you went to the effort to find an existing question, so you should vote to close such questions as duplicates.

Comment: You are right. I submitted a flag as duplicate.